# Python: finding longest version of names

Tags: python, string

I am using python to parse a news article and obtain a set of people names contained within it.
Currently every **Named Entity** classified as a **PER**son (by *Stanford's Stanza* NLP library) gets added to a **set** as follows:

```
maxnames = set()  # initialize an empty set for PER references
for entity in doc.entities:
    if entity.type == "PER":
         if entity.text not in maxnames:
             maxnames.add(entity.text)
```

Here is a **real example** I end up with:

```
{'von der Leyen', 'Meloni', 'Lars Danielsson', 'Filippo Mannino', 'Danielsson', 'Giorgia Meloni', 'Ursula von der Leyen', 'Matteo Piantedosi', 'Lamberto Giannini'}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to keep on the most complete name. In the above example this should become:

```
{'Lars Danielsson', 'Filippo Mannino', 'Giorgia Meloni', 'Ursula von der Leyen', 'Matteo Piantedosi', 'Lamberto Giannini'}
```

because in the first set:

- 'von der Leyen' should be suppressed by 'Ursula von der Leyen'
- 'Meloni' suppressed by 'Giorgia Meloni'
  and so on.

This is how I'm trying but am getting lost :( Can you please spot the error?

```
def longestname(reference: str, nameset: set[str]) -> set[str]:
    """
    Return the longest name in a set of names
    """
    for name in nameset.copy():
        lenname = len(name)
        lenref = len(reference)
        if lenref < lenname:
            if reference in name:
                nameset.add(name)
            else:
                nameset.remove(name)
    nameset.add(reference)
    return nameset


nameset = set()
nameset = longestname("von der Leyen", nameset)
nameset = longestname("Meloni", nameset)
nameset = longestname("Lars Danielsson", nameset)
nameset = longestname("Lars", nameset)
nameset = longestname("Giorgia Meloni", nameset)
nameset = longestname("Ursula von der Leyen", nameset)
nameset = longestname("Giorgia", nameset)

print(nameset)
# should contain exactly: 
# {'Lars Danielsson', 'Giorgia Meloni', 'Ursula von der Leyen'}
```

Comment: I think a `set()` is the wrong data structure here. Typically, people will write the full version of somebody's name the first time it's used, then refer to them using the first/last name only afterwards. People never start with the short form of a name, then start using the full name afterwards. So order matters.

Comment: That's an interesting insight thanks but I'd feel safer not assuming this is always true. I thought about a set for the simple reason that I see no reason to store a string more than once eg. ('Robert','bob','bob','Robert') wouldn't make sense.

Comment: BTW just stumbled on a case that disproves your otherwise intelligent observation :) The article title will often contain only the last name, then in the article body as you say I'd probably find a first use of the full name and thereafter either the first or the last are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't the most efficient solution (O(N^2)), but if the number of names isn't huge I don't think striving for maximum efficiency is that important.

```
>>> names = {'von der Leyen', 'Meloni', 'Lars Danielsson', 'Filippo Mannino', 'Danielsson', 'Giorgia Meloni', 'Ursula von der Leyen', 'Matteo Piantedosi', 'Lamberto Giannini'}
>>> {name for name in names if not any(
...     name in other and name != other for other in names
... )}
{'Matteo Piantedosi', 'Lars Danielsson', 'Ursula von der Leyen', 'Filippo Mannino', 'Lamberto Giannini', 'Giorgia Meloni'}
```

A more efficient solution might involve building a dictionary keyed on space-separated words so you can narrow down the possible set of matches instead of doing an O(N) search each time -- however this gets a little tricky if you have overlaps (say you have "Jean-Claude Van Damme" and "Dick Van Dyke" both in the same article) so I leave figuring that out as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: LOL this borders on magic :) Will go to bed now, wake up tomorrow morning and go through your great solution to understand it. Thanks a bunch!!! PS As you say the average number of names in a sample of 1000 articles is around 10, so  efficiency should not be an issue.